# Добавить кнопки в datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Есть datepicker:
HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control date"  value="{{\Carbon\Carbon::today()->format('m/d/Y')}}" name="date" id="kt_datepicker_3">
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name="date"]').datepicker({
        todayBtn: "linked",
    })

})
```

Есть кнопка Today - это стандарт. Мне нужно еще сделать кнопки с таким функционалом:
 1. Yesterday - вчера
 2. This week - дата от понедельника до сегодня
 3. This month - дата от первого числа месяца до сегодня

Подскажите как это можно сделать? В JS вообще не силен а вот задача есть.

Comment: А что за `datepicker` используете? От какой библиотеки?

Comment: От bootstrap 4 плагин

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте эту информацию в вопрос. Также, дайте ссылку на ваш плагин, потому что их много разных.